# Should there be a different tag for each of the competition venues?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should there be a different tag for each of the competition venues? Or should we wait and see how it goes and split it out if needed? Some I can think of are: USDAA, NADAC, AKC, CPE, ASCA, AHBA... etc. They each have some different rules but maybe it just makes sense to use the "competition-rules" tag and include the venue in the question title?

Comment: I agree with Ashley, but as an addendum, you'd really only want a tag like that if there some idea that there might be sufficient volume to make it worth it as a grouping. If we only got one question for each venue, the tag doesn't help.

Answer (score 7):

Creating tags that aren't currently in use isn't something we do, as the system automatically prunes out any tags that aren't appended to a question after 24 hours. In this case, I don't know a lot about the different rules and how the venues affect them, but I suspect that starting with the competition-rules tag, asking for clarification of venue in the questions as necessary, and going from there, adding tags as there is an active need for them would likely be the best route.

As always, we don't want to create more problems for ourselves than are already presenting on the site. :)

Comment: Also a tag that is not a synonym to any other tag and **is used in only one question** will be deleted by the system after six months.

Comment: @EsaPaulasto That rule does not apply to every site. It can be turned off on a per-site basis, by the SE team.  I suspect that it is on by default, though, even for beta sites, so it probably does apply to us.

Answer (score 4):

A direct answer, as how I see it, is a **no**. Let's keep those competition rules under one tag only. Different associations can be identified in the question title or at least in question body, depending on what the question is about.

This is an international site and while some of those venues reach out to large audiences, there's still thousands of competitions worldwide, each with their own set of rules.  Whenever somebody asks about practices under a certain set of rules, would we address a new tag for that single question? Not likely. Even the question itself might be off the range here.

Would anybody answer my question about show rules in Finland? (Suomen Kennelliitto, Finnish Kennel Club.) Okay, maybe somebody would answer it. Create a new tag for it? No.

Comment: Bytheway, Suomen Kennelliitto is not a small one. We have here one of the largest dog shows in the World. Last such show had over 23000 dogs showed during one weekend. Where can you see more dogs in a single weekend?